# Flex and Yacc - Cannot find - lfl?

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

Hi I'm learing Lex and yacc. I created the following lex program.

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%%
[0123456789]+           printf("NUMBER\n");
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*    printf("WORD\n");
%%
```

I'm trying to run it using the following commands:

1. lex example1.l
2. cc lex.yy.c -o example1 -ll

also tried cc lex.yy.c -o example1 -lfl

When I enter the second command form above, I get error:

```
D:\workdir\flexyacc\Test3>gcc lex.yy.c -o Test -lfl
C:\Dev-Cpp\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lfl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried googling this error but no luck so far. Since I'm new in Lex programming, I'm not understanding how to fix this. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank so much in advance.

Comment: Not sure but think you have your parameters listed wrong have you tried: gcc lex.yy.c -lfl -o Test

Comment: If `-lfl` is not found, are you sure you need it?  Try the build without, and see what happens.  If you get `main()` undefined, then you'll need to write one yourself.  Otherwise, if you get something else undefined, then you need to find the Flex library.

Comment: Hi Kaz, not working for me.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using lex + yacc you can remove -lfl  if you define yywrap function or, even better, if you use noyywrap option:

```
%option noyywrap
%%
 ...
%%
```

Answer (score 7):

To compile the lex code, firstly you should have installed flex in your machine.
If so , there will a file libfl.a. In my machine I've installed flex in 'C:\GnuWin32\lib'

gcc  lex.yy.c  -L"C:\GnuWin32\lib" -lfl

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem and so i checked it out in the Internet and found a solution by workingcaptchabypass posted June 3, 2011 6:44 PM [here](http://mihirknows.blogspot.com/2009/02/undefined-reference-to-yywrap.html)

he said:

> You could add this function instead and compile normally

```
yywrap()
{
}
```

And so i supplied the code in the .lex file before the main function. After doing that, it worked out the way it should :)

Comment: @faye and @caitriiona, yywrap should return a int value! If you want it to "do nothing" it must return a true value, like `int yywrap(){ return 1;}`

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this issue when porting TXR to Windows using MinGW.

MinGW has a flex library for itself, but does not export it to the environment.

See here: http://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/txr-users/2011-10/msg00001.html

The workaround is to use `-L/usr/lib` before `-lfl`. But think about this: it is a hack. Why? Because the path `/usr/lib/` belongs to MinGW, the compilation environment's run-time.

`/usr/lib` is not where the toolchain is supposed to find libs for the Windows program being built (which is it's not in the library search path!)

That is to say, we are effectively stealing the build machine's native library in a cross-compile job.

This is like if you were cross-compiling, say, a Fedora program on Ubuntu, and helping yourself to Ubuntu's static library in `/usr/lib` that happens to be missing in the Fedora cross toolchain (taking advantage of the fact that the architecture and object file format happens to be the same).

It's definitely a bug in the way Flex is "packaged" in MingW.

Comment: The real reason for this may be that GNU Flex does not support cross-compiling very well. In my previous job, I patched Flex to support cross-compiling properly through the usual `--host/--build` options to the `configure` script. I had `flex` being built for the build machine's toolchain, but `libfl.a` being properly cross-compiled to the target machine (which was MIPS).  Without this, Flex just builds both pieces for the build machine, which is what seems to have happend in MinGW: you have a build-machine `flex` and a build-machine `libfl.a`.

Answer (score 2):

After having a hard time trying to fix the same problem as yours, I installed flex-old:

`sudo apt install flex-old`

Answer (score 1):

Try using **-ll** instead of *-lfl* in gcc

Answer (score 1):

If you are on macOSX then replace `-lfl` with `-ll`

Answer (score 0):

For error:
`cannot find -lflx`

In your Makefile change:
`LEXLIB = -lfl` to `LEXLIB =`.

Otherwise remove the `-lfl` argument wherever present.

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

`yum install flex-devel`