# Error while compiling lex program

Tags: gcc, flex-lexer

I installed  Flex 2.5.4a and  gcc compiler on windows. I also 've Dev-Cpp.
To compile the lex program, I used : **flex file.l.**
Now I got lex.yy.c, which I compiled using gcc compiler : **gcc lex.yy.c**.
It gave an error showing:
**c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lfl**

**collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**
though I did include GnuWin32 bin path in path variable in environmental variables.Can someone tell me how to correct this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex and Yacc - Cannot find - lfl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175795/flex-and-yacc-cannot-find-lfl)

Answer (score 3):

If you provide a `main()` and use option `noyywrap`, you don't need `-lfl` anymore...

```
%option noyywrap
%%
  ...your flex
%%
int main(){
   yylex(); 
   return 0;
}
```