# I just started to learn lex. I wrote a program but when I try to compile I receive an error

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I work on Linux Mint and I install lex and yacc with the commands

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install flex
- sudo apt-get install bison

Then I create a file with .l extension and when I try to compile it with the commands :

- lex ex1.l
- gcc lex.yy.c  -ll

After that I receive the error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: `-ll` means you're looking for a library called `libl.so` (or `libl.a`, or otherwise as appropriate for your current platform). What is this library? Where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: I wonder if maybe you want `-lfl`? Note that for many distros (can't speak to Mint specifically), you might need separate a `flex-devel` package. If that's the case, this would be duplicative of the existing question [Flex and Yacc - Cannot find - lfl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175795/flex-and-yacc-cannot-find-lfl)

Answer (score 0):

The library that comes with flex is called `libfl`, not `libl`, so the corresponding flag would be `-lfl`.

If you define your own `main` function and disable `yywrap`, you can also just not link against the library at all.